# Why does my PNG image look different in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, graphics, png

[image]

The image is downloaded from a slide captcha and I'm trying to find the gap in this image with OpenCV.

But the gap is missing in the image opened with cv2.imshow() .
I am not familiar with PNG nor OpenCV so I'm so confused right now.
I searched a lot but found nothing useful maybe caused by using wrong keywords.

image opened with Windows Viewer:
[image]

image opened with cv2.imshow() :
[image]

I'm wondering why the same image in image viewer and OpenCV looks different and is there an easy way to locate the difference?

Comment: The "gap" is not really a color, but a transparency value. `PNG` images have four channels: `Red`, `Green`, `Blue` and `Alpha`. `Alpha` controls how **transparent** the image or an area of the image is. In your image, the gap is a pure transparent value - no color. `imshow` only displays the first three channels, ignoring the `Alpha` values, so that's why you don't see the gap.

Comment: @stateMachine , Thank you, your comment helps me a lot!

Comment: In addition, cv2.imread with default parameters always generates exactly 3 channels and 8 bit per channel, no matter of color depth and number of channels of the image file.